# Can we derive the support vector machines dual formulation without directly using lagrangian duality theory?

Tags: support-vector-machine, constrained-optimization

Lagrangian duality theory allows us to derive the dual formulation for support vector machines and to show that the primal and the dual solutions are equivalent.

My question is: is it possible to derive the dual formulation by a different, simpler approach, such as variable substitution?

Consider the hard-margin problem alone, for simplicity. Could one start by *assuming* that the optimal hyperplane normal vector can be written as a linear combination of the data vectors (a sound and geometrically justifiable assumption), with the dual variables playing the role of coefficients or weights, and use the fact that non-support vectors don't contribute to the solution, to derive the dual formulation without explicitly applying the lagrangian machinery?

**Update:**

I finally figured out how to achieve such a derivation, by following a hint I found in a paper by Keerthi *et al.*, "A fast iterative nearest point algorithm for support vector machine classifier design," in IEEE Transactions on Neural Networks, vol. 11, no. 1, pp. 124-136, Jan. 2000. In the following, I will sketch a brief outline of the derivation.

In the hard-margin version of SVM binary classification, the problem of finding a separating hyperplane with maximum margin turns out to be equivalent of finding the minimum distance between the convex hulls of the two classes of observations.

The convex hull $H_V$ of a set of vectors $V = \{\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_2, ..., \mathbf{x}_n\}$ is the set of all weighted averages of the vectors $\mathbf{x}_k \in V$:

$$ H_V = \left{\mathbf{x} = \sum_k \beta_k \mathbf{x}_k \quad|\quad \mathbf{x}_k \in V, \beta_k \in \mathbb{R}, \beta_k \geq 0, \sum_k \beta_k = 1\right} $$